# Internal working of Tree Set Or Difference between HashSet and TreeSet

Tags: java, set, equals, hashcode, treeset

For TreeSet Sorting for mutable object :

1. If I don't override hashcode equals then for an object having same value for all the fields will be treated as two different object in set as( default objects class hashcode method calculate the hash value of the memory locatuion). So why it is different for the TreeSet. See the below Example.
2. If I just copy a whole Set into a treeSet then why sorting is not happning.

.

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int marks;

    public Student(int id, String name, int marks) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", marks=" + marks + "]";
    }

    public static Comparator<Student> idComparator = new Comparator<Student>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
            return (new Integer(o1.getId())).compareTo(o2.getId());
        }

    };

    public static Comparator<Student> nameComparator = new Comparator<Student>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }

    };

    /*@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + marks;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Student other = (Student) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (marks != other.marks)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }*/

}
```

.

```
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student(1, "A", 50);
        Student s2 = new Student(1, "A", 50);
        Student s3 = new Student(2, "B", 51);
        Student s4 = new Student(3, "B", 51);
        Student s5 = new Student(4, "B", 41);
        Student s6 = new Student(5, "B", 61);
        Student s7 = new Student(6, "C", 51);
        Student s8 = new Student(7, "D", 46);
        Student s9 = new Student(8, "B", 55);
        Student s10 = new Student(9, "E", 51);

        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        studentList.add(s1);
        studentList.add(s2);
        studentList.add(s3);
        studentList.add(s4);
        studentList.add(s5);
        studentList.add(s6);
        studentList.add(s7);
        studentList.add(s8);
        studentList.add(s9);
        studentList.add(s10);
        studentList.add(s1);
        studentList.add(s2);
        studentList.add(s3);
        studentList.add(s4);

        System.out.println("List Initial Size: " + studentList.size());

        List<Student> studentListAfterFilter = studentList.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getMarks() >= 45 && p.getMarks() <= 55).map(p -> p).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("After filtering List Size: " + studentListAfterFilter.size());

        Set<Student> studentSetAfterFilter = studentList.stream().filter(p -> p.getMarks() >= 45 && p.getMarks() <= 55)
                .map(p -> p).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        System.out.println("After filtering Set Size: " + studentSetAfterFilter.size());

        for(Student student:studentSetAfterFilter){
            System.out.println("Set Objects: "+student.toString());
        }

        Set<Student> studentTreeSetAfterFilter=new TreeSet<>(Student.nameComparator);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s1);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s2);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s3);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s4);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s5);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s6);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s7);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s8);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s9);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s10);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s1);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s2);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s3);
        studentTreeSetAfterFilter.add(s4);

        for(Student student:studentTreeSetAfterFilter){
            System.out.println("TreeSet Objects: "+student.toString());
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: What output do you observe when you print your TreeSet?

Comment: Read the documentation carrefully on what defines "equality" in for HashSet and for TreeSet, then read more about "hashCode consistency with equals" and "comparator consistency with equals". This should put you on track.

Also, no need to work with a complex 3 fields object, simplify your example (e.g. just a student name will do) !

Comment: @GPI Thanks, got the answer.